# Use variable in Text Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use a variable in Text Widget, it says Invalid const value, so, I need to use a const, but I'm using Text Widget in a dynamic way. Is there a way to use a Text with variables? or is there another Widget that I could use?

I have something like this:

```
class PlaceCardState extends StatelessWidget {
  PlaceCardState(this._placeCard);
  Place _placeCard;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
            title: Text(_placeCard.title),
            subtitle: const Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
          );
  }
}
```

place.dart

```
class Place {
  Place([this.title = '', this.description = '', this.image='',     this.value=0.0]);
  String title;
  String description;
  String image;
  double value;
}
```

I get this issue:

[image: Text Issue]

Comment: What do you mean "variable"? As in a variable widget or the text needs to change?

Comment: I need to use a variable, like var myText = 'My Text'; and print that into the Text(myText)
but it asks me to use a const, but, in my code, I need to use a class property _placeCard.title, that's a variable, not a const
makes sense?

Comment: I attached a screenshot with the issue

Comment: Does string interpolation not fit your need here?

Comment: In that way I should use something like:
title: Text('I am ${_placeCard.title}'),
but I got the same

Comment: did u check my answer

Comment: I think I got it using the other answer

Comment: I just checked that and it works

Comment: that's great, goodluck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
const ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
        title: Text(_placeCard.title),
        subtitle: const Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
      );
```

into this:

```
const ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
        title: const Text(_placeCard.title),
        subtitle: const Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
      );
```

Since in your screenshot `ListTile` is a constant then all the properties need to be constant also, therefore add `const` before `Text(_placeCard.title),`

Comment: This will only work if `_placeCard.title` is constant as well

Answer (score 3):

`Const` will be assumed for `Icon` and `Text`, as they have to be constant, so that the `ListTile` can be constant as a whole.

So it's the same to write:

```
const ListTile(
    leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
    title: const Text(_placeCard.title),
    subtitle: const Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
  );
```

as

```
const ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
    title: Text(_placeCard.title),
    subtitle: Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
  );
```

But you seem to confuse the meaning of `const` anyway, as this probably won't work in your application.

From [news.dartlang.org,](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html)

> "const" has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart.
>   const modifies values. You can use it when creating collections, like
>   const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new) like
>   const Point(2, 3). Here, const means that the object's entire deep
>   state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object
>   will be frozen and completely immutable

so that means that you could say

```
const ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
    title: Text("foo"),
    subtitle: Text('Come and dance tonight!'),
  );
```

but not create that Object constant while running the application, as you don't have all data at compile-time.

You should just not use const and then it should be alrighto.