# How do I get data from a firebase realtime database and change one text field to represent that specific record?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

This is my first post here so sorry for any confusion!

I recently started using Flutter and I'm new to Firebase too.

I'm using a realtime database as the backend for my app, and I've got a hierarchy that looks like:

[image: database hierarchy]

What I want to do is lookup a specific user by their id, fetch their information (gender and name in this case) and then set a widget (in this case a text widget) to use that value.

How can this be accomplished?

I've searched through a lot of StackOverflow questions about this, and all of them use FutureBuilders or DataSnapshots and I can't quite work out how to go about sorting them out so they work.

All of the tutorials online also don't get info from a specific user and instead query the entirety of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
db.orderByKey().equalTo(Id).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
   values.forEach((key,values) {
     print(values["name"]);
    });
 });
```

First, you get an instance to the node `User`, and then using `orderByKey()` you can search the user by the id, and retrieve the name and gender.

Check the link following for more information:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/query.dart#L183

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand that you're printing it there - how do I assign that to a text widget?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792113/use-variable-in-text-widget

Comment: Great :) The issue I'm having with that is that it's coming up as a full screen error message saying that it's null. I'm assuming because I'm adding that data to the list while the form is being loaded so it doesn't have a value whilst the widget is loading. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Check the example here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: So I just declare it at class level, then set it within SetState (which is inside initState)?

Comment: Got it working :) Thanks so much for all of your help!!